# IE 11 (or 10) kendo ui file upload will not upload unless I refresh the page (ctrl-F5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, windows-authentication, internet-explorer-11

Environment specifics:

- MVC4 app
- Kendo UI File Upload
- IE 11 (or 10)
- Windows Authentication

When I load the view for the application that has the file upload kendo tool in IE the file upload returns a 401 unauthorized error (traced from server). If I refresh the page (ctrl-F5) then the tool works fine. This tool works fine with Chrome.

any idea why or how to fix?

Comment: Got a repro page the IE team could look at? It *sounds* like you're saying that Automatic Authentication isn't happening, which would be a serious bug. If true, your workaround below is probably unstable because it probably relies on ambient authentication in the form of a reused connection.

Comment: none of the table grouping works either

Comment: "Table grouping" may be a user-agent sniffing issue in Kendo. That should be straightforward to test. But your comment doesn't relate to the original question and should be opened with a new question and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

you will not believe the insanity I had to go through to get a solution to this:

I dropped a document ready jquery snippit at the end of the document to force it to authenticate an action on my controller.

```
<div id="checkauth" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '\AcceptanceFileValidator\CheckAuth'
            }).done(function (d) {
                $('#checkauth').html(d.uid)
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and on the controller:

```
public JsonResult CheckAuth()
    {
        return Json(new { uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```